# Is there precision experimental evidence for Furry's theorem -- that only even degree VEVs are non-zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, research-level

Is there precision experimental evidence for or contradicting Furry's theorem -- that only even degree VEVs are non-zero, specifically for the EM field?

Comment: Furry's theorem is a consequence of charge conjugation symmetry in QED. This symmetry is violated by the weak interactions, so I am not sure the theorem is still valid (as a precision experimental fact).

Comment: Thanks, Moshe, I knew I wasn't quite getting the Question right, but I think you've given the Answer to the Question I was trying to ask. Small, because it's electroweak, but I take it there will be odd degree VEVs for the electromagnetic field.